# Changing the HTML code for the Dynamic Sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the dynamic sidebar without hacking the php file.  I'm rebuilding an old web site and I need to use custom HTML code instead of the generate code that's given in wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php.

In a nutshell,  I need to go from:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">LINK NAME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK NAME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK NAME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK NAME</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To this code:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">LINK NAME</a>
    <a href="#">LINK NAME</a>
    <a href="#">LINK NAME</a>
    <a href="#">LINK NAME</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What's stopping you in do that?

Comment: You're giving us a php file and saying don't use php?  If that's what generating the code, you'll either have to give up the dynamic part and hard code the links, or modify the existing function.

Comment: This is maybe quicker answered by the template pros on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (Flag your question for moderator attention to have it moved.)

Comment: Do you actually want list of pages in sidebar, list that is also in navigation menu, only without <li> elements?

Comment: What I was doing was adding a custom menu in wordpress with the pages to the website and adding external links to different websites and it needs to be in a certain order and it has to be the same has there old website.

Comment: @blackbull77: Well, its asked and answered.  Migration would cost @Ivan 25 rep.  Its (barely) on topic, so let's just let sleeping questions lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you want you can create custom menu in admin as you did. Than in page where you want this paste this code:

```
<div>
<?php
  $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items("custommenu");
  foreach($items as $item): 
?>
  <a href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Replace `custommenu` with your menu name.

Comment: Great. WP has many useful functions just try to learn them - it is fun :)

Comment: What if you need to add "target="_blank" to only one of the links?